# Django using a form with an ImageField and a User

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django, the user can upload a comment with the image.

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Comment(models.Model):
  count_votes = models.Integer(default=0)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  thumb = ImageField(upload_to="thumbnails")
  # ...
```

This is what I am trying to do :

```
# views.py
def add_comment(request):
  if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated():
    comment = Comment(user=request.user) 
    form = CommentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=comment)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
  # ...

# forms.py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Comment
```

But there are some errors :

- none of the fields are filled
- the `count_votes` is not defaulted to 0 as I would like to
- the user is not taken into account either
- the image is said to be empty too

How can I achieve that ? I have read many questions on SO and tried various other things, like fill in things in the `__init__` of the form, use `initial` instead of `instance`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure in your template you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag, otherwise the image file will not get uploaded and your form will not validate (and thus, nothing will be added to the database).

In addition, you need to fix your views. Start by using the [`login_required` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) so that your view is restricted to logged-in users, and then fix your form logic:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def add_comment(request):
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
       obj = form.save(commit=False) # create the record, but don't save it
       obj.user = request.user # add the user from the request
       obj.save() # now save the record
       return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

Finally, in your form *exclude* the user because you will be adding it later. In fact, your form should just have the comment and image field. You don't need to include the `count_votes` field because it already has a default value; unless you want the user to modify this field.

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('thumb', 'comment',)
```

Comment: thanks for the comments. regarding the code, the `is_valid` part will return False, because user etc are missing. Exclusion of these fields can work but is there a way for the form to use the default values (e.g count_votes=0) instead ?

Comment: The form will use the default values ... by default. Since the field has a default, saving the record will work.

Comment: works fine. For others it might help, also make sure the `name` property of the image input in html is `thumb` (here)

Comment: You don't need to do that - the form will take care of it. `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}{{ form }}<input type="submit" /></form>`